# Delete complex objects at runtime in Java

Tags: java, null, garbage-collection

In Java, at some point in code I want to free memory taken by a huge `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` object. Is it enough to point it to `null` like below:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> complexObject = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(1000000);
...
complexObject = null;
```

?

Comment: No way of knowing; depends on whether or not anything else has references to objects in the object. Of course, here it's just lists. Also, nulling it out, in general isn't necessary.

Comment: Having a memory-intensive app it is indeed necessary.

Comment: ... That's not how Java GC works. It runs when it wants, and collects what it wants that isn't referenced.

Comment: The problem is this object is kept all the time while I spotted that I could remove it before because GC can find it much before an app finishes.

Comment: Then I'd suggest whatever method it's in is too big; if you need to null it out because it's no longer necessary, it's unlikely the containing method has been broken down appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot explicitly de-allocate Java objects.  But you can do the following:

1. Remove all references to the item you no longer need.  You can do this by setting your only reference to an object to `null`.
2. Call `System.gc()` to "suggest" to the JVM to run the garbage collector, which deallocates no-longer used objects, although it's not guaranteed that calling this method will actually run the garbage collector.

Comment: and it depends of the used garbage collector implementation if it finds all unused objects or just some.

Comment: You should not be calling `System.gc()` at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Setting its reference to null will mark it available to the garbage collector next time it decides to run if there are indeed no more references to said object laying around anywhere. When the GC decides to run however, is not set in stone.

This is a big point where Java is different from C, but don't worry. 99.9% of the time you can trust the GC has your back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of freeing memory. GC will run and pickup nulls so that's all you can do yes.

Answer (score 0):

I just read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html), there is something about freeing memory in it, too.
Check it out, nulling does not always help you.